Duplicate class in 2 different jar files
screenshot I have 2 jar files that must be in the project, but they both have the same class in the same path. These classes differ in content.
I get the error:
Duplicate class cn.pda.serialport.SerialPort found in modules Module_Android_Power.jar -> Module_Android_Power (Module_Android_Power.jar) and reader.jar -> reader (reader.jar)

IMPORTANT! Both jar files must be in the project, and both must use their SerialPort class. I can't just remove 1 jar file, or make them use 1 common SerialPort class.

I tried to decompile the file, change the path, compile it back, but exactly 177 errors appear during compilation.
I tried to split the project into modules. I did it so that in the app module I do not import the module that contains the conflicting jar file, but import the module that imports the module that contains the jar file. It did not help.
I tried to figure out how to resolve gradle conflicts, tried the substitute method, but it didn't work.

How to resolve this conflict?

"How to resolve this conflict?" -- if either of them are an open source project, and if this SerialPort class comes from an open source project, you may have some options. Even if SerialPort is closed source, you might be able to use a tool like jarjar to help. If this is all closed source, though, then I expect that you are out of luck.

You need to exclude the

cn.pda.serialport.SerialPort

class from one of the dependencies. Typically, you'd exclude it from the dependency that's less central to your project or the one you have less control over.
Example (using Gradle):
Assuming reader.jar is the dependency you want to exclude the class from, add the following to your module-level build.gradle file:
dependencies {
   implementation('com.example:reader:1.0.0') {
       exclude group: 'cn.pda.serialport', module: 'serialport' 
   }
   // ... other dependencies
}

Or, if you do not need this dependency at all in your project, exclude it from both jar like this,
android {
// ... other configurations

   packagingOptions {
    exclude 'cn/pda/serialport/SerialPort.class' 
   }
}


If you read OPs post, you will see that this isn't going to work for him. He says that he needs both libraries in  his project and that each library "needs its SerialPort class".
